# What standard is used for the ECDSA to verify transactions?

Tags: transactions, cryptography, signature

Bitcoin used Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm. (see [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses)). I'm wondering what standard is actually used for this Algorithm: which curve? which prime? Can anybody give me a reference? (Wiki gives [this](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf), is this the standard that the ECDSA in Bitcoin?) Anywhere I can find an update on this?

Edit: A bunch of curves are given in page 87 of [this](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). Is bitcoin using one of these?

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Signatures:

> For ECDSA the secp256k1 curve from http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec2_final.pdf is used.

i.e. the curve is

> y^2 = x^3 - 7

and the prime

> p = 2^256 - 2^32 - 2^9 - 2^8 - 2^7 - 2^6 - 2^4 - 1.

See [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) for more information.